# metodos en java

Tags: java

Hacer una clase llamada Zapatería, para calcular el total a pagar por la compra de zapatos que realizan los clientes. Los atributos son los siguientes: cantidad y precio, ambos son privados.

- Crear un método que capture los datos de las variables desde teclado.
- Crear un método que retorne el cálculo del total a pagar por la compra realizada por el cliente, tomando en cuenta lo siguiente: Si se compran dos pares de zapatos o más, se aplica un descuento del 20% sobre el total de la compra y si son menos de dos pares, un descuento del 10%.

Implemente la clase y cree 3 objetos e invoque cada método con cada objeto.

```java
package ejercicio3;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Zapateria 
{
 private int cantidad;
    private double precio;
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
public void CapturarDatos()
    {
        System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de zapatos que comprara: ");
        cantidad=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Ingrese el precio de los zapatos: ");
        precio=sc.nextInt();
    }
    public void TotalPago()
    {
    if (cantidad=>2)
        precio=(double) (precio*(0.80));
    else
        precio=(double) (precio*(0.90));
    }        
 }
```

[image: El segundo método no se como hacerlo si con un if o while]

Comment: No has intentado nada?? Se nota que es una tarea... Aqui ayudamos a solucionar problemas amigo, pon tu codigo, en donde te encuentras atorado y con gusto te podemos ayudar

Comment: Es en el segundo metodo y las disculpas soy nuevo

Comment: ¿Qué problemas o errores tienes? Si el método `TotalPago()` debe devolver el total a pagar, no puedes declararlo `void`. Los métodos `void` **no devuelven nada**, *void* significa vacío en inglés. Debería ser algo así: `public double TotalPago() { if (cantidad=>2) { return precio*(0.80); } else { return precio*(0.90); } }` Como podrás ver, los métodos que retornan algo (no vacíos) deben tener después del modificador de acceso el tipo de dato que retornan (`double`  en este caso) y tener dentro un `return` de ese dato.

Comment: Y cual es el problema?? Aclara tu pregunta, no coloques tu tarea y pon con tus palabras la explicación y el problema

Comment: Gracias @A. Cedano esa parte era la que no entendía muchas gracias